# Updating row in database from android app

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask, sql-update

I'm trying to update a row in my database via my android app. My pulling from the database is working but I'm having trouble with the updating. My code for updating is as follows:

My AsyncTask class:

```
    private class UpdateAnimalTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
 {   
     @Override
     protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0)
     {
            try
            { 
                ID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTid);
                Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTname);
                Type = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTtype);
                Breed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTbreed);
                Gender = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTgender);
                Injuries = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTinjuries);
                Treat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTtreat);

                String nM = Name.getText().toString();
                String tP = Type.getText().toString();
                String bR = Breed.getText().toString();
                String gE = Gender.getText().toString();
                String iN = Injuries.getText().toString();
                String tR = Treat.getText().toString();

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> up = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                up.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", nM));
                up.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", tP));
                up.add(new BasicNameValuePair("breed", bR));
                up.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", gE));
                up.add(new BasicNameValuePair("injuries", iN));
                up.add(new BasicNameValuePair("treatment", tR));

                String phpLink = "http://select.garethprice.co.za/update.php?name=" + nM;
                Log.e("Test", up.toString());
                dbUpdate(up, phpLink);
                Log.e("Test", up.toString());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in uploading " + e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
     }
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
     {
         if(result)
         {
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
     }
 }
```

My dbUpdate method which is being called inside my asynctask class:

```
    public void dbUpdate(ArrayList<NameValuePair> data, String phpL)
{
    InputStream iS = null;

    try
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(phpL);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        iS = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

My php:

```
    <?php
          include_once 'db.php'; 
          $con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)or die("cannot connect"); 
          mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE)or die("cannot select DB");
          $nM = $_GET['name'];
          $tP = $_POST['type'];
          $bR = $_POST['breed'];
          $gE = $_POST['gender'];
          $iN = $_POST['injuries'];
          $tR = $_POST['treatment'];
          $sql = "UPDATE tbl_Animals SET animal_Type = '$tP', animal_Breed = '$bR', animal_Gender = '$gE', animal_Injuries = '$iN', animal_Treatments = '$tR' WHERE animal_Name = '$nM'"; 
          echo "test: " . $nM . $tP . $bR . $gE . $iN . $tR;
          mysql_query($sql,$con) or die("error: " . mysql_error());
          mysql_close($con)
    ?>
```

Executing the asynctask in my update button:

```
    public void Update(View v)
        {
            new UpdateAnimalTask().execute();
        }
```

The android code is not breaking so I suspect it's something with the php because my toast pops up that says update successful in my onPostExecute.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$nM = $_GET['name'];` you sure that's supposed to be a GET and not a POST as you have for the others? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. I tend to pull towards it being `$nM = $_POST['name'];` but I could be wrong. Yet mixing GET and POST, doesn't usually mix well. You can also try `$nM = $_REQUEST['name'];`

Comment: That one is a get because I'm hard coding that one into the url.

Comment: OK, yeah I saw that. Did error reporting yield any errors?

Comment: Try changing `mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE)` to `mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE,$con)` see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I can't upload a new php file at the moment because the person in charge of the ftp is asleep but I'll try in the morning thanx. Btw my echo when I run the php page isn't printing at all.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, try out my suggestion about `mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE,$con)` sometimes that makes a difference. I couldn't help you with the Android stuff though, sorry.

Comment: No problem, will let you know if it works.

Comment: Ok. If someone else gets into the conversation, you will need to add the `@` symbol followed by my name to address me personally, that way I will get notification, *cheers*.

Comment: Roger that @Fred-ii-, I'll run this down :). OP - firstly, avoid the depricated `mysql_*` functions, also debug the query and log the error message from mysql, as that might be your issue.

Comment: Also, you are only testing if the `post` is run successfully in the `onPostExecute()` method. What you want is to test the response. and for that, I suggest sending json in return as it'll clear things up a **whole** lot more!